# Spring Boot basic auth security imposes while starting from embedded servlet container

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am facing an issue in a Spring Boot application. When I am running the app from Tomcat 8 container (not embedded) then on any of the spring boot API end point is getting access without any issues.

web.xml

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <servlet-name>/*</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

Where as if I am starting the same application via main program which is embedded servlet container then I am getting error that the same API need to be authenticated (401 error).

```
{
   "timestamp": 1518739659744,
   "status": 401,
   "error": "Unauthorized",
   "message": "Full authentication is required to access this resource",
   "path": "/api/xyz"
}
```

I have the below bean instance in the configuration of the spring boot which is equivalent to web.xml but still getting the error.

```
@Bean
      public FilterRegistrationBean springFilterRegistration(){
        FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        filterRegistrationBean.setName("springSecurityFilterChain");
        filterRegistrationBean.setFilter(new DelegatingFilterProxy());
        filterRegistrationBean.setUrlPatterns(Arrays.asList("/*"));
        return filterRegistrationBean;
      }
```

Let me know if you have faced any similar issues or came across. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try put

```
security.basic.enabled=false
```

either application.properties or application.yml

Comment: I tried earlier this and it works though. I am not sure though why the basicauth is disabled without application.properties while deploying on external tomcat container and the explicitly needed in embedded container.